# How do I edit the code of a WordPress site?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, comments

I am helping out a family member with their WordPress blog and he/she wanted to have the comments show on the main front page. This way, users don't have to click through the title to add a comment. If that is impossible, he/she wanted to have instructions like "click here to add a comment" near the title.

I know how to write html/css etc., so I would just go in and type in some code but I don't have an FTP account. Is there a way to edit the html of a WordPress site through the WordPress Dashboard menu thing? I would ask for a FTP account, but I doubt he/she knows how to create one. Also, would doing this really screw things up for WordPress? Any and all help is appreciated. If needed I can give the URL, but I would rather not have people trying to post comments and mess around with the site. Thanks!

Comment: I am using Yoko theme if it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is indeed to have an FTP access and edit the blog's theme directly (in `/wp-content/themes/nameofyourtheme`. Otherwise, you can also do it from the Admin panel. Go to Appearance, then click on "Editor". You'll then be able to edit all the theme's files.

**Edit:**

If you want to change the layout of the posts, the file you'll want to edit is `single.php`.

Comment: I find that the problem is not that I want to edit the CSS files, but actually change the way posts are formatted.

Comment: The Admin's editor let you change everything, including the post's PHP code.

Comment: @Eric - Note: in Yoko the file is probably `content-single.php`, additionally, if the front page is showing other post types besides posts, you will probably have to edit the `content` files of those post types too (if they allow comments). - If you get stuck, try http://codex.wordpress.org/

Comment: If you are going to edit a theme directly WordPress actually suggests you create a child theme of your selected theme.  This is to avoid having your changes over written if the theme is updated.  Check out the folllow link for more information. http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the site through the dashboard. When you are making a post you can change it to html and create your own things.

Comment: I was looking for a way to edit the way posts are formatted. For example, a post usually goes title to body to tags. I was looking for a way for it to go to title to body to comments to tags.

Comment: oh. i think you should edit the theme you are using, like Laurent said.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a plugin for this. Which there might even be. But, since i have no idea and fast googling said nothing.

You will have to edit the theme files `/wp-content/themes/Your-Theme/`

You will have to take something like `<?php comments_template(); ?>` from `single.php` file and move it to index.php file somewhere after where you should find something like this `<?php the_content(''); ?>`

- `single.php` Holds the article page.
- `index.php` Holds the "home" page.

---

Is this hosted in wordpress.com?

---

In the control panel you can find **Appearance > editor** in there you can edit the files. Thought i think that it is very likely that you wont be able to save your edits due to file permissions.

---

Also if its a paid hosting they quite often send you these details on email.. I mean Ftp acc and pass.